# i want to show embed video in modal when clicking on image.i used the proper syntax on embed still it is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

```
<!--on clicking this image modal will open-->
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="audi">
    <a class="d-block" data-target="#modalaudi" data-toggle="modal" href="#"><img alt="Audition" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="image/a12.jpg"></a>
    <h4 style="text-align:center">Audition</h4>
</div><!--modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalaudi">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title text-primary">AUDITION</h4><button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">&times;</button>
            </div><!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body mx-auto">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe allowfullscreen class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vnoKLLui7JA"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

First I add image in bootstrap grid that is col-sm-4. On clicking this image one modal should open that will contain video but adding on iframe video is not becoming responsive at all. So I added embed-responsive but still video doesn't appear on modal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `modal-body` where you have your `iframe` didn't have any `width` except that from the `padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px` which is `30px` of width. Not enough to show the video. So just add class `w-100` which adds `width:100%` to `.modal-body`.

`w-100` class works in BS4, not really sure about BS3. But you could add css `.modal-body { width: 100% }` if the class doesn't work

NOTE: the video does not appear in the below snippet because of ( i guess ) Stackoverflow's security but you can see it here -> [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/og4g1vx2/68/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="audi">
    <a href="#" class="d-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalaudi">
    <img src="image\a12.jpg"  alt="Audition" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block">
  </a>
  <h4 style="text-align:center">Audition</h4>
    </div>
<!--modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalaudi">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title text-primary">AUDITION</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
   <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body mx-auto w-100">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vnoKLLui7JA" allowfullscreen></iframe>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this answer helped me to get desired results.

Comment: @anuja if this answer helped you, please rate/accept my answer :D